# Difference for MySQL Error Code 1062 verses 1022

Tags: mysql

Review of MySQL error codes has me confused about the difference between 1022 and 1062 (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html ). I currently don't have access to a test MySQL DB to investigate further.

So, what is the difference between MySQL error code 1022 and 1062 (they both say dup key)?

What gets raised for an attempted insert of an existing Primary Key?

What gets raised for an attempted insert of an existing Unique Key that is not a Primary Key?

Answer (score 2):

Differences between 1062 and 1022 error codes:

- **1062** - is when you attempt to insert a row which results in a duplicated entry, it doesn't matter which type of key (primary, unique, etc).
- **1022** - seems to be used for a different purpose, for example, you can get it when creating a table with a duplicated key.

MySQL reference:

```
Error: 1022 SQLSTATE: 23000 (ER_DUP_KEY)
Message: Can't write; duplicate key in table '%s'
```

```
Error: 1062 SQLSTATE: 23000 (ER_DUP_ENTRY)
Message: Duplicate entry '%s' for key %d
```

MySQL NET constants:

```cs
MySqlErrorCode.DuplicateKey = 1022;
MySqlErrorCode.DuplicateKeyEntry = 1062;
```